# Где хранить нетипичные файлы

Tags: yii2, yii

Вот, допустим, есть у меня php-файлик c самонаписанными функциями, и я хочу его везде подключать.
В какой каталог его класть по правилам этого фреймворка?

Comment: Функции надо завернуть в класс, и подключать его через composerский psr-0/psr-4 автолоадер.

Comment: components (для yii2), очевидно

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225089/which-folder-to-add-custom-helper-functions-to-in-yii

Answer (score 4):

Хранить кастомный файл можно где угодно. Нужно всего лишь работать с пространствами имен и подключать где нужно.

Для примера создадим файл **Person.php** в папке **helpers** в корневой директории проекта.

```
namespace app\helpers; //Указываем пространство имен для подключения в будущем

class Person
{
    public static function showName($name)
    {
        return "Привет $name";
    }
}
```

Для того чтобы подключить выше созданный класс нужно сделать следующее:

```
use app\helpers\Person; //используем пространства имен

echo Person::showName("Urmuz"); //Используем статичный метод класса Person
```

Comment: ТС спрашивал в каком каталоге хранить. Понятно (в теории), что глядя на неймспейс в коде ответа видно, что в components, но, кмк, стоит упомянть об этом ;-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский и как бы это не работает для первого yii почему то. положил этот класс в каталог components и пришлось подключать через include с родным yii алиасом `Yii::import("system.*)."\components\имя_файла.php"`

Comment: @perfect угу, я даже в комментарии к вопросу написал в скобочках что для yii2. Для yii1 не помню. .... более того там и неймспейсов-то нет, так на секундочку ;-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а как связаны неймспэйсы с yii? это же php инструкция должна быть

Comment: @perfect неймспейсы введены в php в версии 5.3.... yii1 была сконструирована еще до введения оной версии... или, как минимум, они не думали об этом. А загрузчики классов и активное использование пространства имен началось только в yii2....... конечно, можно прикрутить и к yii1, но это будет долго и тяжко. Это вам не чаёк с утра заварить)

Comment: Поправлен ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря что там за функции. Можно оформить как behavior или как trait или это helper. Можно вынести на github и подключать через компосер, соответственно попадет в vendor или же закинуть в common в зависимости 
common/behavior
common/trait
common/helpers